# Blazor - EventCallback from Component Launched in Code

Tags: c#, callback, blazor

Im probably going about this the wrong way...

I can get an event call back from a custom blazor component if its called from within the html.

I have some custom toast components that are called from and their position configured c# code.

I would like to get a call back from a button press in on a toast component.

Component Code:

```
public bool HideToast { get; set; } = false;
public ResourceDeleteEventCallbackArgs Args { get; set; }

[Parameter] public IResourceModel Resource  { get; set; }
[Parameter] public EventCallback<ResourceDeleteEventCallbackArgs> ConfirmationChanged { get; set; }

protected async Task OnConfirmation(bool delete)
{
    HideToast = true;
    Args = new ResourceDeleteEventCallbackArgs
    {
        ConfrimDelete = delete,
        ResourceToDelete = Resource
    };
    await ConfirmationChanged.InvokeAsync(Args);
}
```

HTML Button

```
<button class="btn w-35 btn-outline-primary btn-sm mx-1"
     @onclick="() => ShowDeleteResourceToast(r)">
  <i class="oi oi-trash" />
</button>
```

C# code:

```
public void ShowDeleteResourceToast(IResourceModel r)
{
    ToastParameters toastParameters = new ToastParameters();
    toastParameters.Add(nameof(ResourceDeleteToast.Resource), r);
    //toastParameters.Add(nameof(ResourceDeleteToast.ConfirmationChanged), OnDeleteResourceConfirmation);
    toastService.ShowToast<ResourceDeleteToast>(toastParameters, new ToastInstanceSettings(15, false));
}

private async void OnDeleteResourceConfirmation(ResourceDeleteEventCallbackArgs args)
{

    bool delete = args.ConfrimDelete;
    IResourceModel r = args.ResourceToDelete;

    if (delete == true && r != null)
    {
        await resourceData.DeleteResource(r.Id);
        resourcesSortedCollection.Remove(resourcesSortedCollection.Where(x => x.Id == r.Id).FirstOrDefault());
    }
    else
    {
        toastService.ShowError("Resouce not delete", "ERROR");
    }
}
```

Can i trigger the event callback to my function OnDeleteResourceConfirmation without embedding the toast component within the HTML like:

```
<ResourceDeleteToast Resource="@ResourceToDelete" ConfirmationChanged="OnDeleteResourceConfirmation" />
```

Comment: I recommend putting any toast component in the Layout page, and then using a service to manage its state.

Comment: That is what is being done.  I cant figure out how to get a call back from the toast when it is being launched by the service "toastService.ShowToast<ResourceDeleteToast>(toastParameters, new ToastInstanceSettings(15, false));"

Comment: The only thing you should have in any page or component, is simply a call to the service methods.  The business logic should all be on the Layout page.  So you should subscribe to the toast component's custom event on the Layout page.  I have to go to work now, but I can possibly show a working example later today.